# Initialize class-instance and access variables in Swift

Tags: swift

I just created a class and gave it some vars. Unfortunately I can't access these variables in my `iOS-Projects`. However, the same syntax works in playground...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    class Dog 
    {
        var age = 0
        var hungry = TRUE
    }
    var rex = Dog()
    rex.age = 2   //ERROR: EXPECTED DECLARATION
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for a *class declaration* is:

```
class <class name>: <superclass>, <adopted protocols> {
  <declarations>
}
```

Your declaration of `ViewController` includes `rex.age = 2` which itself is not a *declaration*, it is a *statement* - specifically a *binary expression* with an infix operator.

Comment: How should the code look like to make it work properly?

Answer (score 5):

The last two lines need to be inside a function. You can have only declarations in class scope, not expressions to be executed.