# "Expected Declaration" Error in Swift in userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save the placeHolderValue in NSUserDefaults, but I am getting an expected declaration error in the third line.

```
 let placeHolderValue = 1000
 var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 userDefaults.setValue(placeHolderValue, forKey: "placeholder")
 userDefaults.synchronize()
```

I've looked everywhere and can't find someone with a similar problem. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You can omit the `synchronize()` since the OS will do it when it's needed. My Playgrounds accepts the above. Using 6.1.3

Comment: Perhaps you placed that code in a class, but outside of a method?

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041898/initialize-class-instance-and-access-variables-in-swift.

Comment: I just put your code in Xcode 6.3.1 and no declaration errors at all, make a clean and build again or re-open Xcode again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I didn't have the code above within a function. Once I placed it inside a function within my class declaration everything ran smoothly:

```
func test() {

    let placeHolderValue = 1000
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setInteger(placeHolderValue, forKey: "placeholder")


    }
```

Comment: Calling `synchronize()` is not necessary and is not recommended by Apple unless your use falls into the narrow range of cases where they consider it appropriate. This is not one of those cases.